# How can I hide a warning in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For the code:

```
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
c = urlopen(req).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(c)
```

I got the warning:

> WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

I tried with `.decode('utf-8')`, but it gave:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 421: invalid continuation byte

How can I catch this warning, so it will not show in the Python IDLE shell?

When using `warnings.simplefilter("ignore")` in the code:

```
def getimage(url,source):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    c = urlopen(req).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(c)
    m = soup.find('div',{'rel' : 'image_src'})
    return m['href'] 

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    getimage(url,source)
```

I get:

> NameError: name 'url' is not defined

I call the function 'getimage' from another Python file.

Comment: What is the URL ? Any strange looking caracters left by a copy paste operation at the end ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to ignore this warning? Maybe it would be better to figure out what character set the page is actually in, and decode it with that, rather than decoding it as ASCII or UTF-8 or whatever your default is and ending up with `?` characters (and possibly mojibake) in the output.

Comment: URL is a link of a news article. Yes, I am sure tha I want to ignore the warning, since I only want te get the news article image, that's why I am using BeautifulSoup

Comment: It seems the best is to figure out what's the problem, not to ignore it. Some of the pages couldn't be parsed with BeautifulSoup, so I simply skipped them. Thanks everyone that helped on this matter

Answer (score 1):

I got this warning, then got past it, with this:

```
FromRaw = lambda r: r if isinstance(r, unicode) else r.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

That is, pass your raw HTML through it before the soup parse:

```
c = urlopen(req).read()
c = FromRaw(c)
soup=BeautifulSoup(c)
```

It's possible to bullet-proof python against `UnicodeEncodeError` or `UnicodeDecodeError` under any circumstance. The above is half of it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find a fairly comprehensive guide on this exact topic [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html), explaining the types of warnings and how to handle them; One type is specifically `Unicode Warning`. I hope this helps!

Happy coding.

Comment: [Please don't post link only answsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: You're right; I'll repost it as a comment. That's a better idea.

Comment: You don't need to delete it, just copy over relevant information - use the link to *support* your answer, not *as* an answer.

Comment: I tried  warnings.simplefilter("ignore"), but I couldn't make it ignore

Comment: @user1680859 I can't see why that would happen. Would you post the code at the end of your question (input/output) so I can see your implementation of `warnings.simplefilter`?